# git rebase changes commit modification

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I just had this problem today: In the commit `C1` of a branch `Feature1`, a block of code B1 is deleted.

When I do a rebasing of `Feature1` on `Master`, the block B1 is still there. (other changes are fine).

I wonder if this is a bug or if I did something wrong.

Comment: Could you please add the exact commands you followed?

Comment: Rebasing Master onto the branch feature1 will cause master's history to be on top of the feature branch which includes commit c1 because of which the block of code will be removed from master as well. Branch Feature1 will be intact.

Comment: Sorry Sreeram I means rebasing of Feature1 on Master :)

Comment: Well, if thats the case, rebasing Feature1 on to Master will only put the commits in Feature1 on top of Maters commits. It should not remove any commits unless you skipped a commit while rebasing interactively.

Comment: Feature1 >> git rebase master

Comment: You say `Modif M1` disappears, do you mean the block of code is still there?

Comment: The commit C1 is still there but the modifs in it change

Comment: Yes the block of code is still there

Comment: Do you still have the unrebased `Feature1` branch for comparison? You should be able to recover it by referring to `git reflog` if not.

Comment: yes, i added a new commit to fix it. Did the problem occur cause the Feature1 has some merge commit inside it?

Comment: Is C1 an _evil merge_?